# Pyinstaller, errors on windows 10

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am beginner in Python. I was testing pyinstaller, installed it using the venv. I had some issues with my script, so I got to test this only with a basic print('Testing') main.py script.

Tried:
- pyinstaller main.py
Makes the dist folder with exe, but when I run the ext, it flahses and closes. Running the exe inside cmd gives me:

```
Error loading Python DLL 'path-to-project\dist\main\'.
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.
```

- pyinstaller --onefile main.py
  This does not make the dist bundle, I get:

```
File "path-to-project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 365, in cacheDigest
    with open(fnm, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You haven't given much detail on what you are doing, so it's hard to say what might be wrong. The place to start is the `pyinstaller` docs on *When things go wrong* https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html .

Comment: I mentioned that, in the end, I just made a basic main.py containing just a print statement. So, what i was doing before, is not relevant, pyinstaller does not work for me on a basic python script with just a print line. I suspect is related to some windows permission issues.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? PyInstaller has issues with the newest version (3.8). If you can, try it with an earlier Python release like 3.6 or 3.7

Comment: As for your first issue. If your script is *literally* just `print('Testing')` then the flashed console you see is working as expected.It is just executing too quickly for you to see anything. Try putting `input("Press any key...")` after it, or import the `time` module and add a sleep of a few seconds.

Comment: I am using python 3.8. I know the usual beahvior that can run and closes, but i ran the exe file from cmd and I get:

Error loading Python DLL 'path-to-project\dist\main\'.
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.

Tried also with input("Press any key..."), same result.

Comment: I just ran a demo with Python 3.7.3 with the minimal script you suggest (`print('Testing')`). Both modes (single directory and one file) work normally and as I would expect. If you can, I would suggest trying on an earlier version of Python 3.7.x.

Comment: If you suspect it is permissions then try specifying the location of the `build` and `dist` paths explicitly using `--workpath` and `--distpath`.

Comment: @BoarGules tried, no change, might be the python version. Should I just uninstall 3.8 and try fresh install with 3.7? I do not have many global packages so pip freeze and install is not an issue. Is it possible to use different version with virtual environement? I found mixed information about this.

Comment: You don't have to uninstall 3.8. You can have 3.7 and 3.8 side by side. Just be sure to use the right `pip`. As, `...\python37\scripts\pip.exe`.

Comment: Yesh as @BoarGules says, you can have different Python installations at once. The best way is to install 3.7, then create a new venv, making sure to use the Python 3.7 installation to do this (to be sure, you can create with the absolute path to wherever you installed it e.g. `"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" -m venv venv`). Then activate this venv, install pyinstaller and try it out.

Comment: PyInstaller doesn't support 3.8 due to the bootloader changes that version introduced. Are you using standard CPython? From python.org?

Comment: Yes, it is because of 3.8 version. So is there no way to make an exe for 3.8 just using an older python version? That seems weird to me, as a beginner. I mean, I would've expect there is some official package to do this. Thank you all, for answers.

Comment: For people having same issue, I managed to use cx_Freeze to build the exe.

Comment: @Gabriel PyInstaller doesn't support 3.8 *yet*. It's coming in the next release.

Comment: Yes, I understood and confirmed above. Thank you all!